# How to create .der file using RSA private and public key?

Tags: java

I need to read private key and public key using RSA algorithm. So how to create `.der` file?

Answer (score 0):

Using `CertificateFactory`

```
try{
    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    Certificate cert = cf.generateCertificate(new FileInputStream("ca.cert"));
    System.out.println(cert);
}catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```